# What is the meaning of "as if" here?

Tags: modal-verbs, conjunctions, future-tense, modality

What is the meaning of "as if" in B?

> A:The ceiling in this room doesn't look very safe, does it?
>
> B:No, it looks as if it's going to fall down.

Can we omit it?

Another question, can we use **will** instead of **going to...** in B?
I think, we are predicting the future and **will** is more common, isn't it?

Comment: "As if" is used to describe how something seems to be. "It looks it's going to fall down" is not a meaningful sentence in English. "As if" cannot be omitted, but _like_ or _as though_ could be used instead.

Comment: You can replace "going to" with "will" in this sentence without fundamentally changing the meaning. However, it does alter the nuance a little (in American English at least).  I'm not sure if there's an overarching reason but to me, "will fall" sounds more certain than "going to fall".  I feel like "going to" carries a sense of "probably" while "will" carries a sense of "almost certainly".

Comment: @Aref - Why do you think _as if_ could, or ought to be, omitted from the sentence? (Native speakers will almost always use _it's going to_ rather than _it will_ in a conversation like the one you quote.)

Comment: I think you could  omitt "as if" without changing the meaning. As shown here it is used also to replace the conjunction "that".   ***As if*** : http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as%20if

Answer (score 2):

> What is the meaning of "as if" in B?

The sentence is a Simple Sentence with one subject *it* and one verb *looks*. What comes after the verb is called a subordinating conjunction "as if," that is use with an adverb dependent clauses like "as if it's going to fall down." The adverb clause, like a single adverb, modifies either an adjective, verb, or adverb in the sentence. In yours, it is modifying the verb *looks*, and answers, like an adverb "*How*?" (under what conditions); How does it look? As if it's going to fall down.

You can use, "...as if it *will fall* down." The Future Tense "expresses the expectation of action." Because it looks really really shaky, you expect it to collapse at any minute.

Answer (score 1):

Here, *as if* could be replaced with *like* or *as though*. It conveys similarity, but at a distance; just how similar the two things are is vague, unclear, or not yet established. *As if* cannot be omitted or replaced with *that*, because it's required to connect the two clauses and express the particular meaning of uncertain similarity.

B is saying that the ceiling might collapse at some unknown future time. Tone of voice will and context can provide more information to narrow the scope of the statement; in this case, the implication is that B believes if the ceiling were to collapse, it would happen fairly soon.

> Another question, can we use will instead of going to... in B?

Yes. Doing so would change the meaning, though. Both *will* and *going to* are completely routine, correct, and commonplace ways of predicting future action. *Will* is more definite than *going to*, however. It's also more flexible a word in general, so those many different uses are probably what makes it seem a more common choice than *going to*.

Making this change, B's statement becomes more definite: the ceiling is definitely going to fall, and only the timing remains uncertain. The implication of *soon* remains, so it would be a noticeably stronger warning against entering the room.