# What's the meaning of independent "as if"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In *The Kissing Booth 2 (2020)*, Rachel ready to go to school with Elle:

> Elle: What's up, foxy lady?
>
> Rachel: Yeah, right. **As if**.

What's the meaning of independent "as if"?

My question is different from this [one](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/103259/what-is-the-meaning-of-as-if-here) here discuss about "as if" in middle of the phrase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [as if](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as%20if)
> —used to say that something is not true, not possible, will not happen, etc.
> // "I am sure I am very affectionate," said Dora; "you oughtn't to be cruel to me, Doady!" "Cruel, my precious love! As if I would—or could—be cruel to you, for the world!"
> — Charles Dickens
>
> —sometimes used informally as an interjection to say that something suggested or claimed is impossible, incorrect, or ridiculously unlikely to be true
>
> // A simple collection of songs? As if. How about a conceptual ode to London's millennia-old history?  — Craig McLean
>
> // Big budgets? High-priced actresses? As if! The film cost a modest $13 million, a figure achieved by not casting stars, but rather stars-in-the-making …
> — Nicholas Fonseca

Rachel says "as if" to reject the compliment.

As a aid, you could conceivably think of this as *as if that were true/as if I were foxy/as if I were a foxy lady*. But it is unnecessary. She's simply expressing that she does not believe she is foxy.

> → Yeah, right. As if that were true.
> → Yeah, right. I am not a foxy lady.